# k-th largest element in B-tree

Tags: performance, algorithm, tree, big-o, b-tree

How would I modify a B-tree to the find the k-th largest element in O(log[t, n), where `n` is then number of elements already in the B-tree, and `2t` is the maximum number of children  of any node?

I know that the search operation for a B-tree already takes O(logn), but how do I guarantee that the base of the logarithm is `t` as described above?

Comment: Use [subtree size augmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

Comment: Got me on the right track, thanks.